# Не могу удалить SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Когда разбирался с SqlServer мне необходимо было удалить сервер и я ничего лучше не придумал, как удалить вручную. Теперь в службах серверов нет, в Sql Server Configuration Manager нет.
Но в сторонних программах, например в managment studio, при обновлениях или при удалении серверов они отображаются. При попытке удалить или обновить получаю ошибку, мол указанная служба не установлена. Как их удалить окончательно с устройства?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]